# Estoy dando click en un commandButton de Primefaces y no hace nada, se requiere de dar otro click para que funcione

Tags: primefaces

Este es la llamada del boton en la vista .xhtml

```
<p:commandButton title="Nueva Solicitud"
   styleClass="FLeft"
   icon="fa fa-plus white" 
   actionListener="#{dispatchView.initCreate()}"
   action="solicitud.xhtml"
   update="item-list-form,messages"
   value="Nueva Solicitud"/>
```

En el Bean  correspondiente el código es como sigue:

```
@Named(value = "dispatchView")
@SessionScoped
public class DispatchRequestController extends RequestController implements Serializable {

....

    @Override
    public void initCreate() throws IllegalStateException, SecurityException, SystemException, IOException {
        creating = true;
        editing = false;

        selectedItem = new Request();
        selectedItem.setCode(configService.getDocumentNextCode(Document.TYPE_DE_SEM));
        selectedItem.setDateRequest(LocalDate.now());
        selectedItem.setSourceArea(areaService.findOneById(Area.AREA_MATPRIM1));
        selectedItem.setDestinationArea(areaService.findOneById(Area.AREA_DESPACHO));
        details.clear();
        selectedItem.setRequestDetails(details);
    }


....
}
```

El Bean del que extiende es RequestController con esta estructura.

```
@Named(value = "requestView")
@SessionScoped
public class RequestController extends BaseController implements Serializable {

...

    public void initCreate() throws IllegalStateException, SecurityException, SystemException, IOException {
        creating = true;
        editing = false;

        selectedItem = new Request();
        selectedItem.setCode(configService.getDocumentNextCode(Document.TYPE_MP_SEM));
        selectedItem.setDateRequest(LocalDate.now());
        selectedItem.setSourceArea(areaService.findOneById(Area.AREA_ALMUEB));
        selectedItem.setDestinationArea(areaService.findOneById(Area.AREA_MATPRIM1));
        details.clear();
        selectedItem.setRequestDetails(details);
    }

...
}
```

Y el BaseController posee la siguiente estructura.

```
@ViewScoped
public class BaseController implements Serializable {
....
}
```

El RequestController tiene un comportamiento similar y funciona perfectamente.
Por favor alguien qué me explique como resolver este problema. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La necesidad de presionar dos veces el commadButton para que se efectuara la llamada era debido a un error de programación en la vista .xhtml, pues se hace un include a un archivo que tiene un modal pero dicho include se hacia antes de la etiqueta form de la vista principal, quedando la etiqueta form del modal dentro de la etiqueta form de la vista, generando esta incompatibilidad tan dificil de detectar.